# Use of Acronym tags

Tags: discussion, tags

I think we should discourage acronym tags like "tftfv". I assume it means Tales froma  Floating Vagabond, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Pet peeve, but that's an **initialism** not an **acronym**.  See http://www.lyberty.com/encyc/articles/abbr.html.

Answer (score 1):

We acronymize a lot of other games -- [nwod], [dd], etc. Obviously Tales from the Floating Vagabond is somewhat more obscure but I am not sure where to draw the line. I just created an [info page](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tags/tftfv/info) for [tftfv] -- does that ability help resolve your concerns?

Comment: And now I'm having fun writing info pages. Whee!

Comment: Info pages work great!

Comment: Whoa whoa, how does one _create info pages_!?

Comment: Heh! OK, you click on the tag. At the very top, you will see something like 'The mysteriousgame tag has no wiki, would you like to help us create it?' You click on the link, and you go to the wiki page. The catch: you need to have 1,000 reputation and you need to either be in the top 20 answerers for that tag or you need to have a total score of 100 or more for that tag.

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62341/lower-reputation-required-to-write-tag-wiki-on-private-beta-se-sites

Comment: nice!  yeah, with an info tag it's fine.

Answer (score 1):

Do people actually refer to Tales from the Floating Vagabond as tftfv outside this site? I hear NWoD and D&D on a regular basis...

Also, tftfv is a tough acronym to parse :-P

Comment: Yep. The top Google hit on TFTFV is Troll and Toad, it's used as a tag on Library Thing, and so on.

Comment: @Bryant Then it should be fine. The important thing is that people who play the game will recognize it in a list of questions.